# list command in gdb not outputing the code that i wrote

Tags: c++, cmd, gdb, g++

i wrote a simple c++ code and compiled it with the following command in the command prompt but when I open the executable in the gdb through the (cmd) and when I ask it to list code lines I get the following order 
I tried to change the containing folder but I was not successful

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Welcome! \n";
}
```

this is  the c++ code I want to see gdb outputting when I input the list command 
but instead I get this error

I compiled this code with the following command

```
g++ -fno-stack-protector -o executable mycode.cpp
```

I also tried using it with out the stack protector argument

```
../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was missing the -g argument in the compiling process

```
g++ -g -fno-stack-protector -o outputfile.exe inputfile.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Please notice  '<<' operator when you use 'cout':

```
int main(){
    cout << "Welcome! \n";
}
```

if you would like to use gdb source debuging, you should use -ggdb3 option.

Comment: how to use the -ggdb3 option

Comment: @WeedCookie, that sounds like another, _(different)_, question. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the question posted at the time of this answer, do not use the responder as free support outside of the original issue.

Comment: g++ -ggdb3 mysource.cpp -o myprog.exe